# Matplotlib 2d histogram and setting limits. Feature or bug?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I'm having a peculiar issue with Matplotlib.  I want to know if it's behaving as it should, and I should adjust my thinking, or if it's a bug, and I should create an issue.

Before I get into it, I'm using matplotlib version 1.5.3 within Jupyter notebook, Python 2.7.

**The peculiarity**:  *When I plot a 2d histogram (`ax.hist2d`), and then set the axis limits (`ax.set_xlim`) the figure size depends on the limits.*

Here is a working example:

First the setup:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plt
%matplotlib inline

#Create some data:
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.001)
y = np.sin(x)
```

This works as expected:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist2d(x,y)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: A nice, full-size plot]

Setting the x-lim to something smaller than the range of data produces a smaller plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist2d(x,y)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim([0,0.1])
plt.show()
```

[image: A tiny plot]

*Edit: Under closer investigation, the plot is the same size, there is just a huge amount of empty space in the output image to the right of the plot, causing the browser to shrink the image*.

With the 2d histogram removed, it behaves as I'd expect:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.hist2d(x,y)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlim([0,0.1])
plt.show()
```

[image: An appropriately-sized plot]

Comment: Seems to be a bug of matplotlib as your code looks correct. I observe the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you found a solution?